# VueJS prop is undefined when read in data() method

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

I'm having trouble understanding how props work in VueJS, some help would be greatly appreciated. It is a simple google map component that I wish to show on the page and pass the id element of the div dynamically as a prop to the underlying template.

html file -

```
<div id="app">
    <google-map name="map"></google-map>
</div>
```

vue file -

```
<template>
    <div :id="mapName"></div>
</template>

<script>
module.exports = {
    name: 'google-map',
    props: [ 'name' ],
    data: () => {
        console.log(this.name); // ERROR: name is undefined
        return {
            mapName: this.name
        };
    },
    mounted: () => {
        const map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById(this.mapName), {
            zoom: 14,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.305, -76.617)
        });
    }
}
</script>

<style scoped>
#map {
  width: 800px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background: gray;
}
</style>
```

The error I get is that `this.name` is undefined inside the data() method of the component object.

Comment: Remove `name` and `data` altogether; and use `name` instead of `mapName`. Explanations in the introduction part of the [guide](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/).

Comment: If you wish to send `name` and use `mapName` in the child component, add a computed property: `computed: { mapName: () => this.name }`.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

the reason that `console.log(this.name);` returns undefined is you are using Arrow function. It should be

```
data: function() {
    // ...
},

mounted: function() {
    // ...
}
```

or

```
data() {
    // ...
},

mounted() {
    // ...
}
```

**Explanation:**

See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks

[image]

Comment: That was the reason... Thanks a lot!

Comment: You saved my day! just wondered why it's not working actually?

Comment: @AmirrezaNasiri see the warning section in https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks =]

Comment: @JacobGoh Oh I got it! my mistake.